# Why must Chromium Embedded Framework be run as root? (Unity Installer)

Tags: unity-game-engine, chromium-embedded

I'm installing Unity.  The Unity installer says it must be run as root, and this is because Chromium Embedded Framework must be run as root.  Why must Chromium Embedded Framework be run as root?

The Unity installer points me [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150414040309/https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandbox), but that page doesn't mention root permissions.

Here is the console output, for posterity:

```
lol@localhost:unity(0)\ ./unity-editor-installer-5.4.0b23+20160628.sh
This installer must be run as root.
```

And the relevant code snippet from the installer:

```
# chrome-sandbox requires this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandbox
chown root "${EXTRACT_SUBDIR}/Editor/chrome-sandbox"
chmod 4755 "${EXTRACT_SUBDIR}/Editor/chrome-sandbox"
```

EDIT July 15: Found [this thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=598454).  Can someone help confirm that root ownership and SUID are no longer needed on chrome-sandbox?

I'm building according to [these instructions](http://dev.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-guide) but am still asked for root password when I run cros_sdk.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure everyone uses the same exact environment and tools to build with Chromium, all building is done inside a `chroot`. This chroot is its own little world: it contains its own compiler, its own tools (its own copy of bash, its own copy of sudo), etc.

It uses `chroot`, `prctl` and few others syscalls which can return `EPERM error` if the process has insufficient privileges.

[EPERM error](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html)

Therefore the installer wants to run a bash script that is run as root for setting SUID on the sandbox. They want you as root because it gives file owner’s `permissions` as well as owner `UID` (User ID) and `GID` (Group ID). Generally in Unix/Linux when a program runs it inherits access permissions from the logged in user.

[Chromium OS Developer Guide](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-guide)

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Acquiring root access, in order to limit permissions, is what I still don't understand.  At no point should elevated privileges be required.  The command `fakechroot` can be used instead of `chroot`.  The function `prctl` can do several different things, and only some require root access.

Comment: I apologize that the bounty wasn't awarded, this answer is well-researched.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium Embedded Framework doesn't need to be run as root. Root permissions are only required to set permissions/chmod on the chrome-sandbox executable. Installers on Linux usually require root permissions, there is nothing strange about that.

Comment: Most applications can be compiled and run as a normal user.  The Unity installer just extracts Unity into a subdirectory.  Why does chrome-sandbox need to be owned by root and have SUID set?